# How to make a property required on POST but not on PUT requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Let's say I have an User model which has `Email` and `Password` properties for authentication purposes, as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to make these properties required only on POST requests, but not on PUT. That is: Email and Password fields are required to create a new user. But when editing I can omit these properties. I know that this goal can be archived removing the `[Required]` from Email and Password and checking for these properties when POSTing, but this does not seem to be a good practice.

So, there is a more elegant solution for this use case?

Comment: Then use separate models for the different actions.

Comment: this is generally done by creating separate models for login. you can check the structure by using `dotnet new mvc -au Individual` in CLI and check the project

Comment: You could design your own request handler, where you can perform different actions based on the method (POST, PUT, etc). For your particular example above, I might not recommend it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use an Entity as input/output parameters. Instead, create two separate view models that represent the actions being called:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

// When creating, the client cannot know the Id because it doesn't exist
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

// and when updating, the Id is required but not the Email nor the Password
public class UpdateUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, since you are creating an API, "View Model" might not make a lot of sense. You may use the Data Transfer Object (DTO) term instead.

Comment: Hi Camilo! Great answer, thanks! One point: Instea of re-declaring all properties in `UpdateUserViewModel` can I extends `User` and add the properties relative to credentials? Is it a good practice?

Comment: @BrunoPeres Glad to help. I would not mix ViewModels, which should center on the clients of your services, with entities, which should represent your internal business logic. This is one of the places where the DRY principle doesn't really apply, and having duplicate code can be good

Comment: Right. So I should: 1) Always persist an User entity; 2) When POSTing, I should receive a CreateUserViewModel instance; 3) When PUTing I should receive a UpdateUserViewModel instance. Right?

Comment: @BrunoPeres Exactly! You will see that pattern if you create a new project with Individual User Accounts (aka Identity)

Comment: any way to avoid code reuse? lets say i got `MaxLength` variables. i would like all models to have this. but lets say i change my entity

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to use View Models. In your case, you could have a RegisterViewModel that takes all of the values from the model and then you could have an EditViewModel that doesnt include email and password. In your controller, your edit function can either replace the old values for the other field or just ignore them.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1174826/Using-MVVM-in-MVC-Applications-Part